# Client Can't Connect to WDS Server

Tags: ip, wds, windows-server-2016

I'm running a WDS machine (Server 2016 Technical Preview) on a Hyper-V machine.  I've set it up.  I've set it to respond to all clients.  However, when I try to pxe boot to it I get "contacting 192.168.1.76" and it just keeps trying forever.  It does this until about 30 periods show then I cancel it.

Here's the ipconfig on my WDS machine:

[image]

And what my pxe boot is showing:

[image]

So what's possibly going on?

Comment: This is an issue with the WDS part of the server server. The client is connecting to the network and downloading the initial files from the PXE server (same as the WDS server, PXE bootstraps the WDS system). Something is wrong with the WDS part. Can you create a new reminstall folder (WDS folder) and see if that fixes the WDS server?

Answer (score 0):

Your should check if you have enabled WINS on your Network card (under TCPv4 Settings) of your WDS Server. When yes, disable it :)

[image]

Comment: could you verify this?